# Is it advisable to have a getter that return a different value than that set by the setter?

Tags: python, return-value, getter-setter

I feel that this is practical for my purposes but also a bit confusing since one might expect to get the same output as the input.

```
@property
def value(self):
    return next(
    (option.key for option in self._options
     if option.id == self._value),
    None)

@value.setter
def value(self, value):
    idoption = None
    if isinstance(value, Option):
        idoption = next(
            (option.id for option in self._options
             if option.id == value.id), None)
    elif isinstance(value, int):
        idoption = next(
            itertools.chain(
                (option.id for option in self._options
                 if option.key == value),
                (option.id for option in self._options
                 if option.id == value)
            ), None)
    elif isinstance(value, str):
        idoption = next(
            (option.id for option in self._options
             if option.key == value), None) 

    if idoption:
        super()._set_value(idoption)
    else:
        raise InvalidOptionError(entity=self.entity_name,
                                 field=self.name,
                                 value=value)
```

When running:

```
company.value = 123
print(company.value) # returns company_1
```

Comment: Seems a bit subjective, but... I think it's fine, although it may be prudent to explicitly point out the behavior in the documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your setters and getters are performing significant work, they really aren't setters or getters any more. Although the code is correct, I would recommand renaming (one or both of) the functions, so that it is clear when using them that they are not simple getters and setters. Something like:

```
company.set_value_option_record(123)
print(company.extract_value())
```

Unless you absolutely need to use the `@property` and `@value.setter` decorators for some reason. In that case be sure to document it explicitly for users of your class.